# Error handling in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to differentiate "page not found" and "resource not found" errors.
Is it possible to get the exception type to do something like the following?

```
def render("404.json", assigns) do
  case assigns[:reason] do
    NoRouteErro -> message = "Route not found"
    Ecto.NoResultsError -> message = "Resource not found"
    _ -> message = "Uncaught exception"
  end
  ContactService.ResponseHelper.error(message)
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have that almost right; the patterns you're matching against are incorrect. To match the struct type of a struct with `case` (and ignore the value of any fields of the struct), you need to use a `%` before and `{}` after the struct's module name. You should also do the assignment outside the `case` to prevent Elixir's "unsafe variable" warning. I've also switched to pattern matching in the function head instead of using `assigns[:reason]`.

Final code:

```
def render("404.json", %{reason: reason}) do
  message = case reason do
    %Phoenix.Router.NoRouteError{} -> "Route not found"
    %Ecto.NoResultsError{} -> "Resource not found"
    _ -> "Uncaught exception"
  end
  # ContactService.ResponseHelper.error(message)
  %{error: message}
end
```

With this code, I get the following results:

```
$ curl -H 'Accept: application/json' http://localhost:4000/404
{"error":"Route not found"}
$ curl -H 'Accept: application/json' http://localhost:4000/api/contacts/1
{"error":"Resource not found"}
```